Why acceleration is not always parallel to velocity but velocity is always parallel to displacement?
Velocity is derivative of displacement :
$$\vec v=\frac{\mathrm {d\vec r}}{\mathrm dt}$$
And acceleration is derivative of velocity.
$$\vec a=\frac{\mathrm {d\vec v}}{\mathrm dt}$$
Given that their definitions looks very similar, why is it the case that acceleration is not always parallel to velocity but velocity is always parallel to displacement ?
My teacher told me that I'll learn about it in higher classes due to high level mathematics. So, I'm looking for an intuitive answer if possible.

Because velocity is the derivative of position but acceleration isn't? What kind of answer are you looking for here? Velocity is a change in position (over time), and so the velocity points in the direction of the displacement (i.e., the change in position), provided the time interval is short enough. Acceleration is the change in velocity over time, so it always points in the direction of changing velocity (provided the time interval is small enough).

@march Sorry , I was confused and thought displacement and position vectors are same.

They are not! You should draw a picture of an object at two different positions, draw the position vectors for each position (an arrow pointing from the origin to the positions), and then draw the displacement (which is the difference between the two position vectors)

@march Yes I understand. I made a blunder recalling their definitions.


... but velocity is always parallel to displacement ...

This is where your mistake lies. Velocity is not always parallel to displacement.
Consider an object travelling in a circle. At time $t=0$ it is at $A$. At a later time $t=t'$ it is at $B$ on the opposite side of the circle. Its displacement at $t=t'$ is $\vec{AB}$ which is a diameter of the circle. But its velocity vector at $t=t'$ is a tangent to the circle and so is perpendicular to its displacement.

I got answer of my question but I was talking about instantaneous velocity and instantaneous displacement.

@An_Elephant Then the answer is because instantaneous displacement is $d \vec r$ whereas instantaneous velocity is $\vec v$ not $d \vec v$.

@An_Elephant If by "instantaneous displacement" you actually mean "position", then of course velocity isn't always parallel to position. What is true is this: average velocity is parallel to displacement.

Velocity is parallel to change in position vector ( displacement vector) similarly not velocity vector but change in velocity vector is parallel to acceleration vector.

This answer essentially just restates the OP's question.  OP is asking for why this is true or at least for an intuitive understanding for this fact. Please expand on your answer.

He actually made a mistake in taking analogues in those differential equations. I gave my answer based on correct analogues. But anyways he seems to have realised the mistake quickly


why acceleration is not always parallel to velocity but velocity is
always parallel to displacement?

Acceleration can be due to a change in speed and/or change in direction of an object. It can be perpendicular and/or parallel to velocity.
When acceleration is due only to a change in direction with no change in speed, there is no acceleration parallel to the velocity, only perpendicular. This is the case for uniform circular motion where the speed of an object is constant but the direction of its motion is continuously changing. The centripetal acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity. However the displacement of the object occurring along the path is always parallel to the instantaneous velocity. There is no displacement perpendicular to the velocity, that is, towards the center of circular motion since he radius of the circular motion is constant.
When acceleration is due only to change in speed but not direction, the acceleration is parallel to the velocity. However again the displacement of the object is parallel to its velocity.
Hope this helps.

$a^i = \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^j} \frac{dx^j}{dt} = \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^j} v^j$
$\Rightarrow a^i v_i = \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^j} v^j v^i \neq 0$
because $\frac{\partial v^i}{\partial x^j}$ is in general not 0
Trivia
in SR
$v^\mu v_\mu = 1$
and $a^\mu := \frac{dv^\mu}{d\tau}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{d (v^\mu v_\mu)}{d\tau} = 2 a^\mu v_\mu = 0 \Rightarrow  a^\mu v_\mu = 0$ but this does again not imply $a^i v_i = 0$
